# Unity issue: no launcher nor other bars (Ubuntu 16.04)

Tags: unity, ubuntu

Yesterday I reboot the system to enter my Windows partition and use a program. When I logged back into my Ubuntu account I got a black screen (in guest session everything was fine).

I made some research and, using the `nomodeset`, I managed to enter my account avoiding getting a black screen afterwards. So now I can access my Ubunto account, but the side launcher is not shown, as well as any other bars: when I open the terminal (only working through right click on the desktop) or a webpage the top bar is not shown as well, so I cannot minimize/close windows. The top desktop bar is also gone, so I cannot control volume or shut down via graphic mode.

Trying to get Unity back to its natural state I followed intructions from this [**link**](https://askubuntu.com/questions/475296/unity-launcher-and-top-panel-disappeared-in-14-04) (answer with 29 votes), and this other [**link**](https://askubuntu.com/questions/17381/unity-doesnt-load-no-launcher-no-dash-appears) (answers 412, 145 and 44). With the the last one I managed to enter the *CompizConfig Settings Manager*, but in my case the *Ubuntu Unity Plugin* doesn't have a box do enable/disbale, contrary to the image shown in that answer:

[image]

(If I enter the Unity Plugin it seems to be enabled, though.)

I also checked that no nVidia drivers were accidentaly installed as I read in some other links, as I'm not running on nVidia graphics.

The last change I remember doing on the system before the failure was trying to install **Wine** so I could run Photoshop CS5. For some reason it didn't manage to be installed, and if I acceed my Ubuntu account a message pops-up, something related to **mscorefront**.

The last option I have is to copy all my documents to a hard-drive and re-install Ubuntu, but without the launcher and my poor skills it could be a nightmare.

I hope you can give me a hint on how to solve this issue. Again, the problem is only when I enter my Ubuntu account; on guest session or in the log in panel everything looks fine.